# Why in Material3 TopAppBar does not have content parameter instead Material

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Example in Material3

```
TopAppBar(
    title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = titleRes)) },
    navigationIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = onNavigationClick) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = navigationIcon,
                contentDescription = navigationIconContentDescription,
                tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
            )
        }
    },
    actions = {
        IconButton(onClick = onActionClick) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = actionIcon,
                contentDescription = actionIconContentDescription,
                tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
            )
        }
    },
    colors = colors,
    modifier = modifier.testTag("niaTopAppBar"),
) {   here error   }
```

but in Material we can. Why TopAppBar in Material3 does not have content, it is difficult to customize, in Material we can

Comment: It used to have two variation one with parameters and one without just a RowScope but i think they removed I'm not sure. Because according to google material 3 guidelines all you need to follow is them is the slots provided but the params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **content** parameter has been removed in Material 3.

[Material content param](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/AppBar.kt;drc=08889769d8d7f33060b2198d3faf0d91f1fc3815;l=227)

Material 3 has special slot structures for all variations.

[Material 3 AppBar types](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.material3/material3/1.0.0-alpha01-source/androidx/compose/material3/AppBar.kt.html)

Comment: By the special slot structures you mean, small medium large app bar? They are not so different

Comment: Why they have removed param content, it is convenient to have and just pass, instead of have multiple simillar components, i think

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be to adapt to the design system.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Answer have helped